# How to specify customizations in devcontainer template?

Tags: visual-studio-code, templates, vscode-devcontainer

I am creating a .devcontainer for `vscode`. I want the users of that devcontainer to be able to debug their code using a specific debugger. If not using .devcontainer, the user would have to add a `launch.json` file in the `.vscode` directory. I want to add the settings of the `launch.json` file to the .devcontainer, so the users don't have to bother about creating a `launch.json` file. How can this be done?

Thanks for reading!